# How to move an application to another stack in Qtile?

Tags: window-management

It seems that there can only be two split windows allowed in Qtile Window Manage. If I want two applications to be side by side, how to move one from stack-1 to stack-2?

Suppose I have three applications in this split layout:

| Emacs, Chrome | Evince|

How can I put Chrome to the right window view?

| Emacs | Chrome, Evince|

**Update**:

Although I still don't konw how to move window to another stack, I found a new approach when I was using `xmonad`:

```
use workspaces.
```

Move the window you don't want to display currently to another workspace, let it get out of the way. So that you can manage the remaining window well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems what you want is a binding for `lazy.layout.client_to_next()`. That will move the current window from the current stack to the next stack.

FYI, you can have more than 2 stacks with the Stack layout - just pass a different value for the `stacks` argument. For example:

```py
layouts = [
    layout.Max(),
    layout.Stack(stacks=3),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Qtile has many layouts. To have many stacks you can use Monadtall layout or to have more stacks in config (with stack=Num) for simple stack layout.

For commands to more your windows, look at [example-config](https://github.com/qtile/qtile/blob/develop/libqtile/resources/default_config.py)  or read [documentation](http://qtile.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/config/).